# Use Process.Start to execute a File on a Shared Folder

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to start a new Process by using Process.Start() which works great when I pass in

```
   Process.Start("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Upload.exe")
```

but is it possible to perform that same operation when I move Upload.exe into a shared folder under My Network Places? I tried

```
   Process.Start("\\Shared Folder\\Upload.exe");
```

but I get a Win32Exception. Thanks for any information or suggestions in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the UNC form be something like \\\\Computername\\ShareName\\Shared Folder\\Upload.exe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use UNC path for accessing a network resource. (Your file becomes a network resource when you place it in a shared path)

UNC path takes the following form.

```
\\ServerName\SharedPath\YourFile.exe
```

or

```
\\ServerName\D$\SharedPath\YourFile.exe
```

where D$ is the drive letter.

In your case you may have to use the following

```
Process.Start(@"\\Server-Name\Shared Folder\Upload.exe");
```

Use @ symbol in front of the string because your \\ will be treated as \, as an escape character.

Answer (score 5):

Try either: `"\\\\Shared Folder\\Upload.exe"` or `@"\\Shared Folder\Upload.exe"`